# SwiftUI view is not updated but the model has been updated correctly

Tags: swiftui

I try to build a counter.
Here is my model:

```
var encoder = JSONEncoder()
var decoder = JSONDecoder()

class CounterItems: ObservableObject {

    @Published var counterItems: [Counter]

    var index = 0

    init() {
        counterItems = []
    }

    init(data: [Counter]) {
        counterItems = []
        for item in data {
            counterItems.append(Counter(id: index, name: item.name, count: item.count, step: item.step, isDeleted: item.isDeleted))
            index += 1
        }
    }

    func AddNewCounter(newCounter: Counter) {
        counterItems.append(Counter(id: index, name: newCounter.name, count: newCounter.count, step: newCounter.step, isDeleted: newCounter.isDeleted))
        index += 1
        storeData()
    }

    func minus(index: Int) {
        if counterItems[index].count >= counterItems[index].step {
            counterItems[index].count -= counterItems[index].step
        }
        storeData()
    }

    func plus(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].count += counterItems[index].step
        storeData()
    }

    func edit(index: Int, data: Counter) {
        counterItems[index].name = data.name
        counterItems[index].step = data.step
    
        storeData()
    }
 
    func reset(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].count = 0
        storeData()
    }

    func resetAll() {
        for item in counterItems {
            reset(index: item.id)
        }
        storeData()
    }

    func delete(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].isDeleted = true
        storeData()
    }

    func deleteAll() {
        for item in counterItems {
            delete(index: item.id)
        }
        storeData()
    }

    func storeData() {
        let dataToStore = try! encoder.encode(counterItems)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dataToStore, forKey: "counterItems")
    }

}
```

Here is my view:

```
struct ContentView: View {



@ObservedObject var userData: CounterItems = CounterItems(data: initUserData())

@State var isShowingAddCounterView = false
@State var isShowingResetingDialog = false
@State var isShowingDeletingDialog = false


var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(userData.counterItems) { item in
                            if item.isDeleted == false {
                                SingleCounterView(index: item.id)
                                    .environmentObject(userData)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Tally Counter")
                
                HStack(spacing: 130) {
                    Button(action: {
                        isShowingResetingDialog = true
                    }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    })
                    .alert(isPresented: $isShowingResetingDialog) {
                        Alert(title: Text("Will reset all counters"),
                              primaryButton: .default(
                                              Text("Confirm"),
                                              action: {userData.resetAll()}
                                          ),
                              secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
                        )
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        isShowingAddCounterView = true
                    }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingAddCounterView, content: {
                        AddCounterView().environmentObject(userData)
                    })
                    
                    Button(action: {
                       isShowingDeletingDialog = true
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    })
                    .alert(isPresented: $isShowingDeletingDialog) {
                        Alert(title: Text("Will delete all counters!"),
                              primaryButton: .default(
                                              Text("Confirm"),
                                              action: {userData.deleteAll()}
                                          ),
                              secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct SingleCounterView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userData: CounterItems
var index: Int
@State var isShowingEditingView = false


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color("Color\(index%5 + 1)"))
            .frame(height: 150)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .padding([.trailing, .leading])
            .shadow(radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Button(action: {
                userData.minus(index: index)
                HapticManager.instance.impact(style: .medium)
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
            })
            
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                
                Button(action: {
                    isShowingEditingView = true
                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        Text(userData.counterItems[index].name)
                        Text("\(userData.counterItems.first(where: {$0.id == index})!.count)")
                            .font(.system(size: 60))
                            .frame(width: 100)
                    }
                    
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingEditingView, content: {
                    AddCounterView(userData: _userData, name: userData.counterItems[index].name, step: userData.counterItems[index].step, index: index)
                })
                    
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    SingleCounterFullView(index: index).environmentObject(userData)
                }, label: {
                    Image("quanping")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    })
                
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
            
            
            
                Button(action: {
                    userData.plus(index: index)
                    HapticManager.instance.impact(style: .medium)
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        
        
        }
    }
}

func initUserData() -> [Counter] {
    var output: [Counter] = []
    if let storedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "counterItems") as? Data {
        let data = try! decoder.decode([Counter].self, from: storedData)
    for item in data {
        if !item.isDeleted {
            output.append(Counter(id: output.count, name: item.name, count: item.count, step: item.step, isDeleted: item.isDeleted))
        }
    }
}
return output
}
```

All these functions work well in live preview and simulator.
But when running on my iPhone 12, the `count` of a single counter in `SingleCounterView` sometimes is not updated until I press the plus or minus button of another SingleCounterView. However, `userData.counterItems[index].count` is still updated and works well.

e.g.
I have a counter named as "Books", the current `count` is 3. When the plus button is pressed, `count` in `SingleCounterView` is not updated to 4 until I press another plus or minus button in another counter. But count in `SingleCounterFullView` is always right and updated after plus or minus is pressed.

Comment: Is Counter a struct or a class ? (Should be a struct)

Comment: I forgot paste counter struct. Yes it is a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Note : The problem can happen on any counter but only on one at a time. Once a counter as the issue, it continue with it. It does not always happens.
Seems that using binding may suppress the problem :

```
                    ForEach(userData.counterItems) { item in
                        let index = item.id
                        if item.isDeleted == false {
                            // pass the array item instead of index in array
                            SingleCounterView(counter: $userData.counterItems[index])
                                .environmentObject(userData)
                        }
                    }
```

Updated the view to use a binding to the array element

```
struct SingleCounterBindingView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: CounterItems
    @Binding var counter: Counter
    var index: Int {
        counter.id
    }
    @State var isShowingEditingView = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Button(action: {
                counter.minus()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .padding()
            })
            
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Button(action: {
                    isShowingEditingView = true
                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        Text(counter.name)
                        Text("\(counter.count)")
                            .font(.system(size: 60))
                            .frame(width: 100)
                    }
                    
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingEditingView, content: {
                    AddCounterView(userData: _userData, name: counter.name, step: counter.step, index: index)
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    SingleCounterFullView(index: index).environmentObject(userData)
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                })
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                counter.plus()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .padding()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Created a counter struct to handle modifications :

```
struct Counter: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var count: Int
    var step: Int
    var isDeleted: Bool
    
    mutating func plus() {
        count += step
    }
    
    mutating func minus() {
        if count >= step {
            count -= step
        }
    }
    
    mutating func reset() {
        count = 0
    }
    
    mutating func delete() {
        isDeleted = true
    }
    
    mutating func edit(from counter: Counter) {
        name = counter.name
        step = counter.step
    }
}
```

// Updated  model to use Counter new functions

```
class CounterItems: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counterItems: [Counter]
    
    var index = 0
    
    init() {
        counterItems = []
    }
    
    init(data: [Counter]) {
        counterItems = []
        for item in data {
            counterItems.append(Counter(id: index, name: item.name, count: item.count, step: item.step, isDeleted: item.isDeleted))
            index += 1
        }
    }
    
    func addNewCounter(newCounter: Counter) {
        counterItems.append(Counter(id: index, name: newCounter.name, count: newCounter.count, step: newCounter.step, isDeleted: newCounter.isDeleted))
        index += 1
        storeData()
    }
    
    func minus(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].minus()
        storeData()
    }
    
    func plus(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].plus()
        storeData()
    }
    
    func edit(index: Int, data: Counter) {
        counterItems[index].edit(from: data)
        storeData()
    }
    
    func reset(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].reset()
        storeData()
    }
    
    func resetAll() {
        for item in counterItems {
            reset(index: item.id)
        }
        // note storeData is not needed
    }
    
    func delete(index: Int) {
        counterItems[index].delete()
        storeData()
    }
    
    func deleteAll() {
        for item in counterItems {
            delete(index: item.id)
        }
        // note storeData is not needed
    }
    
    func storeData() {
        let dataToStore = try! encoder.encode(counterItems)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dataToStore, forKey: "counterItems")
    }
}
```

Note: I suppresses all colors and haptic to simpilfy sample code
Note 2 : I assume that index and item.id where equivalent as it seems in your example. But index could be a computed var using firstIndex.

Comment: Thanks! This issue has been perfectly solved!